# Magento overriding template in custom module

Tags: magento

I have problem with overriding template in custom module. I installed new theme in frontend. Below I created files:

*/etc/modules/Category_ImageProduct.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Category_ImageProduct>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Catalog/></depends>
        </Category_ImageProduct>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*/app/code/local/Category/ImageProduct/etc/config.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Category_ImageProduct>
            <version>0.0.1</version> 
        </Category_ImageProduct>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <category_imageproduct_layout>
                    <file>category_imageproduct/category_imageproduct.xml</file>
                </category_imageproduct_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*app/design/frontend/evoque/default/layout/category_imageproduct/category_imageproduct.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <default>
        <reference name="ev_leftmenu">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>category_imageproduct/leftmenu.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I want to override template name leftmenu.phtml which is defined in block in layout */app/design/frontend/evoque/default/layout/local.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
             <block type="evoqueconfig/navigation" name="ev_leftmenu" template="evoque/leftmenu.phtml" before="-">
                  <block type="cms/block" name="ev_promotion_under_catalog">
                      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>ev_promotion_under_catalog</block_id></action>
                  </block>
               </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Above is cut of piece of code from layout file */app/design/frontend/evoque/default/layout/local.xml*. But still template is not overriden. I add text to new template to notice the change but I don’t see any changes. How do I fix?

Comment: hi it is not possible to change template which define in local.xml because local.xml loaded at the end after all *.xml loaded. so it overide all handle define in local.xml

Comment: From what I know in file /etc/modules/Category_ImageProduct.xml we should insert module name that we want to load first before our module in tag <depends/>. I use <dpepends><Mage_Core/></depends> but I don't see any changes. What module name I should use in <depends> tag to get it worked in frontend?